# XSL: how to convert this 004 to just 4

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I have some XML that looks like the following:

```
<vteam id="004">Visiting Team</vteam>
```

I am attempting to just retrieve the value `4` from it by using the following in my XSLT (1.0):

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="number(vteam/@id)"/>
```

This is giving me a compilation error. What's the right way of going about it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just do this...

```
<xsl:value-of select="number(vteam/@id)"/>
```

Or, depending on what else you were doing, this...

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="vteam"/>

<xsl:template match="vteam">
   <xsl:value-of select="number(@id)"/>
</xsl:template>
```

(Of course, the **xsl:apply-templates** would have to be inside a separate template)